# Create a CSSStyleSheet object from a CSS string?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a baked-in solution for converting a CSS string to its respective CSSStyleSheet object?

In short, I want to transform some arbitrary CSS (i.e. `.foo {} .bar {}`) into a `CSSStyleSheet` object.

I see the CSSStyleSheet object has an `insertRule` method, but that doesn't help me much as I don't have the CSS split into individual rules, and maybe that's doable with some regex magic, but I would have to write a proper parser to do this properly I guess.

Is there an elegant way to do this that doesn’t involve writing a parser?

Comment: create a style element ... add the CSS string to it .. and the element to the DOM ... or am I misunderstanding the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that does this:

```js
function CSSString2CSSStyleSheet ( css ) {
  const style = document.createElement ( 'style' );
  style.innerText = css;
  document.head.appendChild ( style );
  const {sheet} = style;
  document.head.removeChild ( style );
  return sheet;
}
```

Comment: I'm happy you were able to find a similar question, that question, nor any of its answers, do not contain the word `CSSStyleSheet` anywhere, I suppose that's why I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically construct a style sheet using [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet). Then, you can apply it by adding it to the document's [adoptedStyleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptedStyleSheets) array:

```js
const css = `
    body
    {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
`;

const myStyleSheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
myStyleSheet.replace(css);

document.adoptedStyleSheets.push(myStyleSheet);
```

```html
<p>Notice the black background and white text, as prescribed by the dynamically created style sheet.</p>
```

Comment: This produces a constructed CSSStyleSheet, which can be reused with shadow Components. Firefox does support this since mid '22.